# string between each occurrence

Tags: python, string, each, between

What would be the formula if you need to repeat a word with a string between each occurrences? For example we have the word dog and the string ', between ' how do I do it so that between is between each dog occurrences?

Comment: `', between'.join(['dog', 'dog', 'dog'])`

Comment: Or maybe a little more general  `', between '.join(['dog'] * 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `join` like so:

```
res = ', between '.join(['dog'] * 4)
print(res)
```

Comment: is there another way without using join??

Comment: Well if you want to just print it out you can do. `print(*['dog'] * 4, sep=', between ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can get that one by using the **`join()`** function

```
result = ', between '.join(arr)
print(result)
```

Where arr is the list containing the required word for 'N' number of times

Check the documentation for **`join()`** function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

Comment: is there another way without using join??

Comment: Yes, there is where you can concatenate the string using the `+` operator.

Comment: I tried to use "+" but then at the end I get 'between', I need it to finish with dog, is there something that I am doing wring? I tried (dog*4)+', between '

Comment: You should go till the second last number of times instead of the last number and then at the end simply add the string to the resultant string, i.e. if you want to have dog for 4 times then use a loop that runs 3 times and adds up 'dog' and ', between' while storing it in a string. Now at the end of loop simply add the 'dog' string to the resultant variable which had stored during the loop